# Pro's and Con's to moving inetpub on WFE

Tags: iis

So i've read alot of articles on how to reconfigure the IIS logs to an alternate drive for SharePoint.

One question that comes up in my head is are you able to move the inetpub folder to another drive and still keep sharepoint alive?

Anyone know of any Pro's and Con's to this idea?

Thanks!

Comment: I would think as long as you move the default folder in IIS6 of the smtp and sharepoint, then everything should work great.

Comment: Thank you both for the reply and thoughts, in my research I had come across the same idea that Per Jakobsen mentioned about moving IIS before any web apps are created this way sharepoint only knows of one location. If i'm working in an existing environment where i have one WFE that is setup in the default location, I may run into issues when i try to introduce another WFE (Loadbalancing) that is configured with inetpub on a different drive. I did find a pretty useful thread that talked about the topic and the various parts of the move if I were to do it. http://forums.iis.net/t/1073841.aspx Th

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be no problem in moving the logs, but if you want to move the entire inetpub folder including the homedir of the SharePoint Web Application then you should do it before you create the Web Application or you'll have to delete the existing Web Application create them again using the new homedir and attach the databases.

YOU SHOULD NOT JUST MOVE INETPUB AND CHANGE HOMEDIR IN IIS!!!!!
If you do this then SharePoint will still try to make all of it's changes to web.config in the old place when you deploy new WSPs.

The advantage of moving is that you can keep even more changing files away from the C-drive
The disadvantages of moving is that the extra drive have to exist on all WFE servers (and APP servers if they work as local WFEs) and that it might confuse other admins.